# Deploying a vue project to surge.sh

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, travis-ci, surge.sh

I've been trying to deploy my Vue project to Surge.sh all day, the project uses the `webpack-simple` template.

The funny this is, if I deploy it manually from my CLI, it'll work, but if I push it to GitHub and deploy it from Travis CI, it won't work. If I deploy it from Travis, it won't include the `dist/` folder so the site won't work.

Here's my Travis CI configuration :

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"
  - "7"
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules/
    - dist/
install:
  - npm install
after_success:
  - surge --project . --domain mydomain.surge.sh
```

And I did added two enviroment variables, which is `SURGE_TOKEN` & `SURGE_LOGIN`. I really don't know what do right now. So please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your `dist` folder is missing after the Travis build step is because the environment is cleaned up after each step.

In order to prevent this, you need to specify a `deploy:` section in your `.travis.yml` and set the `skip_cleanup: true` setting.

Luckily for you, Travis CI [supports Surge.sh deployment directly](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/surge/), so you don’t need to use the `surge` CLI tool directly in an `after_success` step. Have a look at the linked instructions above and see how you go.

**Update:**

I think you need to add a `script:` step to build your site before you deploy it. Otherwise I don't think [this command](https://github.com/caxvis/musik/blob/master/package.json#L10) is being called by anything else.

Something like:

```
install:
  - npm install
script:
  - npm run build
deploy:
  provider: etc...
```

Comment: I've tried to implement your suggestion into my travis config but it still won't deploy correctly, here's my current travis config, let me know if anything is wrong

Comment: Updated my answer.